# How to choose a common-mode choke for DisplayPort 1.4?

Tags: pcb-design, emc, common-mode-choke

I'm trying to pick a CMC for a DisplayPort 1.4 interface which I'm going to impalement in my design.

I came across this [LCFE121002A900TG](https://www.mouser.co.il/datasheet/2/240/Littelfuse_EMI_Filter_LCFE_Datasheet.pdf-1372327.pdf) CMC which I found at [Mouser](https://www.mouser.co.il/ProductDetail/Littelfuse/LCFE121002A900TG?qs=EU6FO9ffTwficxqfPY60FQ%3D%3D) (let's say I'm interested in the 1210 size).

Note: I tried to pick something close to the Intel Reference Design of the Gen 11th motherboard, but all the information they had in the design were the 100 mA and 90 Ω parameters next to the CMC symbol, and I have no idea in what context they come.

I know that DisplayPort 1.4 has a maximum total bandwidth of 32.4 Gbps and a maximum total data rate of 25.92 Gbps.

In my understanding, what I'm seeing in figure 1 is that when the common mode noise has a frequency of 100 MHz, the impedance that of the choke is 90 Ω. Is that correct?

And also, does this 90 Ω have anything to do with the impedance matching with the 85 Ω ± 15 of DP?

Figure 1:
[image]

Second, does Figure 2 mean that we "just" lose -3 dB of the differential signal when we go up to 10 G, which means that we only lose -3 dB of the "data" that we want to deliver?

Figure 2:
[image]

Finally, from Figure 3, I see that at 100 MHz, the insertion loss of common is around -7.5 dB, which means (in my understanding) that we got rid of -7.5 dB of the "bad signal". Is my analysis right?

If yes, how does this CMC comes into play when we go above 100 MHz, lets say 5 GHz and 6 GHz, and how is it appropriate for the DP 1.4?

Figure 3:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, just select a CM choke which has a datasheet that says it is suitable for DisplayPort 1.4.

The choke you talk about can handle 100mA (more than enough for data lanes) and it has 90 ohms as some parameter, but it is unknown what exactly, but most manufacturers say it is 90 ohms common mode impedance at 100 MHz.

But it does not have anything to do with DisplayPort differential pair impedance, which is 100 ohms (it is not like you say it is 85 ohms). The filter must pass the differential signal as much as it can and remove common mode signal as much as needed.

If you look at the datasheet you linked, it says it is good for up to DP 1.2 at 5.4 Gbps, has cut-off of 3.7 GHz and CM impedance of 90 ohms. Since it does not explicitly say it works with DP 1.4, it is unknown if it works, but DP 1.4 is 8.1 Gbps per lane and the linked datasheet says it works with USB 3.1 Gen 2 at 10 Gbps, so it might work.